# How to configure curl to only show percentage?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, curl

Is there an option for the curl command to show only a percentage output to shell rather than all of this, for example:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.4M  100 12.4M    0     0  4489k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 4653k
```

Maybe there is a flag I can set? If not, pipe it somehow through a regular expression to show me a continuous update of the percentage only?

Thanks all

Comment: If you are parsing the value's sent, what are you using to do so? You might consider using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect to create a wrapper utility: hide all the parsing complexity in the Expect script and just output what you need.

Comment: I am using PHP's popen function and storing the output into a text file. I am having a look at your reference link, it looks quite complicated!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Two modifiers might help, although neither are exact: `--silent` will suppress all updates and `--progress-bar` will show a progress bar only.

Edit: One option to make things easier would be to make a wrapper using [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to simplify the output to your shell script or whatever is listening to curl.

Answer (score 11):

Does the parameter `-#` solve your problem?

> -#/--progress-bar
>
> Make curl display progress information
>   as a progress bar instead of the
>   default statistics.

From [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-).

Comment: That's looks interesting but I am going to be capturing the percentage, is there a way for it not to be so interactive?

Comment: I don't have CURL installed to test it, but I think this displays some type of bar and the percentage in the middle (or somewhere else). Can you pipe this and filter the numbers out to get the percentage?

Comment: My command line skills isn't exactly good! But I tried piping the output to this " | grep -o '[0-9]*'" - however nothing came up. Even if it did, would it do this continuously as the number changed? Maybe a loop needs to be used?

Answer (score 10):

You might want to try the `-#` option.

It shows a simple progress bar and percentage downloaded.