# Curl progress meter and bar problem. It duplicate data

Tags: bash, curl, progress-bar

I have script that final stage is download files with curl. I need to show progress of downloading. When I type on terminal `curl -# $url - O` it work good. I use it with

```
while read line
do
"curl code"
done <url
```

In that case it start filling my screen with #. Default progress meter do that to. It start filling my screen with progress data. 
[here is picture if you dont understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmmkG.jpg)

[progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIQbu.jpg)

In curl documentation there writed that they fixed it.

İf I can't solve this problem how I can show only percentage of progress? It can cuted with `sed` but i don't know how.

Comment: Did you try the `-s` option?

Comment: I need to show progress.

Comment: What about redirecting something to `/dev/null` ?

Comment: I am new at scripting and don't understand what it mean.

Comment: I don't use curl that much so I don't really know the issue but try adding `2 >/dev/null` at the end of the `curl` command. It may or may not work but it is worth a try.

Comment: I tried to add that but curl see it like host. Tried to fix it but it stopped working

Comment: Does this answer your question [Extract download progress from curl output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139990/)?

Comment: I don't know why but it not doing anything ¯\(°_o)/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your question

> How I can show only percentage of progress?

this seems not to be possible easily according [CURL Progress Bar: How to pipe and extract numbers only using grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132456/curl-progress-bar-how-to-pipe-and-extract-numbers-only-using-grep) or without a wrapper according [curl progress - only show percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132185/curl-progress-only-show-percentage).